Function App: Azure.Storage.Blobs: Value cannot be null
I have published a function from Visual Studio 22 but I get two errors. I go to the configuration in Function App to see the value of AzureWebJobsStorage. In this place I saw AzureWebJobsStorage 's value and It is same connectionString of my Visual Studio solution (the string I get from Storage Account > Access keys).
I don't know why AzureWebJobsStorage return a fail: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').

Can you share the code which you have tried?

Did you run the application successfully in local?  and are you able to deploy the function successfully into portal?

Can you give more information about your issue? then it would be reproducible.

Hello! I don't share code because I am not using Git. My solution work fine, save many blobs in Storage Account container section.

Can you add your storage connection string in the function app  environment variables in portal?

Yes, my storage connection string (Storage Account > Access keys) is on in Functions's App Configuration: AzureWebJobsStorage DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=iniciacionazuredevst;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Can you check any unnecessary spaces or invalid characters in connection string.

I have similar problem. One configuration works on osx, but the same thing does not work on a windows machine. I am getting the error on the Auzre.Storage.Queues parameter.

The solution: you have to go to Function Api > Environment variables > App settings and add the variables that we have in the project in the local.settings.json file.
Thank you very much for the help and sorry for the absence.


Function App: Azure.Storage.Blobs: Value cannot be null

The above error message indicates that there might be a problem with how connection string is being utilized in code and the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string in your Azure Functions configuration.

Verify that the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string is correctly set in your Azure Functions configuration.
The connection string is copied correctly from your Storage Account > Access keys into the Azure Functions configuration like below:



Must be add storage connection string in function app environment variables.



After added the appsetting need to redeploy the function into portal.

The key must be same in local and portal configuration of storage connection string.



Yes, i have this configuration but the problem persist.

Ensure your configuration of connection string of key must be same in local and portal.

Can you redeploy the function once and check?
